# update a richtextbox from a static class

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
namespace SSS.RemoteTruckService
{
  public partial class Startup : Form
  {
    private Timer _gpsTimer;
    private Timer _ppsTimer;
    private Timer _creditCardTimer;
    private Timer _iniTimer;

    public string Message
    {
      get { return richTextBox_Message.Text; }
      set
      {
        richTextBox_Message.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() 
          => richTextBox_Message.Text = DateTime.Now + " " + 
          value + Environment.NewLine + richTextBox_Message.Text));
      }
    }

    public Startup()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      StartRemoteTruck();
    }

    private void ButtonPauseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (_gpsTimer.Enabled) _gpsTimer.Enabled = false;
      if (_ppsTimer.Enabled) _ppsTimer.Enabled = false;
      if (_creditCardTimer.Enabled) _creditCardTimer.Enabled = false;
      if (_iniTimer.Enabled) _iniTimer.Enabled = false;
      ProcessIniFile.StopProcess();
    }

    public void StartRemoteTruck()
    {
      Message = "RemoteTruck started.";

      if (Settings.GlobalSettings == null)
      {
        Message = "GlobalSettings was null or not loaded. Cannot continue.";
        Logging.Log("GlobalSettings was null or not loaded. Cannot continue.", "RemoteTruck", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
        Environment.Exit(0);
      }

      if (Settings.GlobalSettings.IniFileWatcherEnabled)
      {
        ProcessIniFile.StartProcess();        
      }

      CreateTimers();      
    }
```

And in the `ProcessIniFile.StartProcess()` I have the code:

```
namespace SSS.RemoteTruckService.inifile
{
  public static class ProcessIniFile
  {
    private static DateTime _iniLastWriteTime;
    private static readonly string Inifile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "sss.ini");
    private static FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    public static void StartProcess()
    {  
      ReadIniFile();
      SaveCurrentIniReadings();
      CreateIniFileWatcher();
    }

    public static void StopProcess()
    {
      if (_watcher != null)
      {
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        _watcher = null;
      }
    }

    private static void CreateIniFileWatcher()
    {
       _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
          Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),
          NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
          Filter = "sss.ini"
        };
      _watcher.Changed += SssIniWatcherChanged;
      _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```

I'd like to pass back the the calling form the status of the reads of the file watcher.

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but if I want to add to the `Message` on the main form, how do I get to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Events for that. Your process can send events and your form can handle them.
More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: can you offer a suggestion on which event I should hook on to or a small code example?

Answer (score 0):

The simple but not pretty way I like to use is to make that part of the form static as well. For example, creating a static variable `WriteMessage`, and in your Form Load or `Startup()`, you can set it:

```
WriteMessage = (s) => Message = s;
```

Sure this has some issues, but it's a quick way to get it done. One of those issues is that, you may need to use `Dispatcher.invoke` if you're not on the UI thread.